# deep layered XML parsing

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath

Thanks in advance for your help. I do appreciate it.

I'm new to parsing xml in powershell and I need to be able to extract the data from the following xml path: (see the hierarchal layout)

```
<Configuration>
    <ABC>
        <DEF>
            <GHI>
                <JKL>
                     <MNO>
                         <item itemName="FileExclusions">
                              <STV>
                                   <exclusionList>
                                        <item..1>
                                        <item..N>
```

I don't know how to get past the `<item itemName="FileExclusions">` using the following XPath in the `Select-Xml` command:

```psh
$VARmyXml = [xml](get-content "c:\readThisXMLFile.xml")
Select-Xml -xml $VARmyXml -xpath '/Configuration/ABC/DEF/GHI/JKL/MNO[./STV/exclusionList/@itemName, "FileExclusions"])'
```

The ultimate goal is to capture the strings contained in `<item1>`..`<itemN>` in the `<exclusionList>` node.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following XPath :

```
/Configuration/ABC/DEF/GHI/JKL/MNO/item[@itemName = "FileExclusions"]/STV/exclusionList/*
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still missing something. When I execute this command using your argument it doesn't return anything. it doesn't fail outright with a red colored error message but it doesn't return anything. 

How can I get it to return the contents of the item1...itemN?